# How to get eclipse debugger to skip $$EnhancerByCGLIB$$ methods?

Tags: eclipse, cglib

I want to skip over methods generated by CGlib I have added *$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$* to my eclipse step filters but still eclipse does not skip these, here is my configuration. How do I configure the step filter to get to skip any CGLib enhanced methods?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding *CGLIB* and checking Step through filter seems to have fixed the problem for me. below are the filters that I am using, it turned out I had to filter EnchancedByCGLIB and FastClassByCGLIB.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain a bit further? Did you just add the text 'CGLIB' as a step filter? Or does it require any wildcards?

Comment: @CollinPeters I have added a screen shot with what I am currenty using.

Comment: Thanks. FYI I see a possible typo. *FastCLassByCGLIB* has a capital L in Class.

Comment: I am voting against this because it doesn't work with my Eclipse 2023-03 (JDT 3.19) even though the settings in the window captured make sense. Several people have voted for an enhancement request against Eclipse which requests that very possibility: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=377663
If this really worked for you, please mention in which version. It could be a regression that wildcards no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

While I have no experience w.r.t. CGLib, I'd suggest adding a class filter, not a package filter to Eclipse.

Comment: In order to add a Class Filter, you have to specify an actual class.

Comment: Despite the confusing icon, they're actually "filters", not package filters. As maxxyme, wrote, a class filter can only filter one class.